# how return parent products , RecursiveField in rest api?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

I don't have return parent in products rest api django.
when i request sub-categories in url show parent recursive
,but when i request products in url  parent field  is empty.
please help me, thanks.

serializers.py : i have used RecursiveField.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from products.models import Product, SubCategory
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField


class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      parent                      = serializers.ListField(read_only=True, source='get_children', child=RecursiveField())


      class Meta:
           model = SubCategory
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      subcategory = SubCategorySerializer(read_only=True)


      class Meta:
          model = Product
          fields = ('id', 'name', 'subcategory',)
```

models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class SubCategory(MPTTModel):

       name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
       parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')


       class MPTTMeta:
             level_attr = 'mptt_level'
             order_insertion_by = ['name']


       def __str__(self):
             return self.name


class Product(models.Model):

      name                  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       subcategory           = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

urls.py

```
 from products.views import (ProductViewSet,
                        SubCategoryViewSet)

 from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


 router = DefaultRouter()
 router.register(r'products', ProductViewSet, basename='product')
 router.register(r'sub-categories', SubCategoryViewSet, basename='subcategory')
```

views.py

```
from products.models import Product, SubCategory
from products.serializers import ProductSerializer, SubCategorySerializer
from rest_framework import mixins, generics



   # Create your views here.
    class ProductViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

           serializer_class = ProductSerializer
           queryset = Product.objects.all()


   class SubCategoryViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

           serializer_class = SubCategorySerializer
           queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub-categories/ ==> show parent:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn0Vr.png)

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/ ==> does not show parent
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6JA.png)

Comment: which version of django-rest-framework and djangorestframework-recursive you are using ?

Comment: i use of :    Django==2.1.7
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-mptt==0.9.1
djangorestframework==3.9.1
djangorestframework-recursive==0.1.2
pytz==2018.9

Comment: please add your **get_children** as well

Comment: **parent = serializers.ListField(read_only=True, source='get_children', child=RecursiveField())**. ->>>> You are only getting children instead you need to get all the family.

Comment: thanks @bkawan i change to=>>> **parent                          = serializers.ListField(child=RecursiveField(),source='get_ancestors',read_only=True)**. and fix problem.